# Export entire html <table> to a text document using Watir

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

Basically all I would like to do is export a whole html table to a .txt file (notepad document).

So far I have learnt how to instruct the browser to find the html page with the table.

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'hpricot' 
require "watir-webdriver" 
url = "http://www.example.com"
browser = Watir::Browser.new 
browser.goto url
```

After running the above in cmd I can now see the html table in the browser.

This is where I am stuck. How do I use Watir to

1. Find the  tag
2. collect everything (i.e. the html ,  and the text) which is within  and .
3. Extract those results to a .txt file (notepad document) and save it in a specific folder.

FYI the html table looks like this...

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<th> Address </th>
<th> Council tax band </th>
<th> Annual council tax </th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> 2, STONELEIGH AVENUE, COVENTRY, CV5 6BZ </td>
<td align="center"> F </td>
<td align="center"> &pound;2125 </td>
</tr>
```

....... The above row is repeated many time ......

```
</table>
```

Then the table is closed.

So to re-cap my situation. I can use Watir to navigate the browser to the page containing the html table but my problem is that I am unsure of how to extract the results (everything within the  tag - including the html) to a .txt file and then save that .txt file onto my computer.

I would prefer to take smaller steps with using Watir. I am knew to it therefore I would just like to learn how to extract the table and save everything that I have extracted into a .txt file. I have seen a couple of examples online using hpricot. However most of the examples seem to miss off code detailing how the array (if that is the correct approach) is outputted into a .txt file.

Could you help by demonstrating how to write a simple piece of code which will extract the html table ( and everything, including the ,  and everything in between) to a .txt notepad file?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: You probably do not need this: `require 'hpricot'`

Comment: As an introduction to Watir, I would recommend the free version of my Watir Book: https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/downloads

Comment: Why do you need the HTML of the table?

Comment: are you sure you'd not rather have just the text from the table? do you really want the raw HTML?

Comment: It's strange that multiple questions are coming in this week requiring both hrpicot and watir-webdriver.  I wonder if a blog is to blame.

Comment: @ Željko Filipin: Thank you for all of your advice.

Comment: @ Chuck van der Linden: Ideally I would like to just have the text but as I am new to this I thought if I could just understand the basic concept of selecting and extracting one html tag to a text file it would give me a basic example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get HTML of the entire table (if it is the only table on the page):

```
browser.table.html
```

You will get something like this:

```
=> "<table border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"2\">\n<tbody><tr>\n<th> Address </th>\n<th> Council tax band </th>\n<th> Annual council tax </th>\n</tr>\n\n<tr>\n<td> 2, STONELEIGH AVENUE, COVENTRY, CV5 6BZ </td>\n<td align=\"center\"> F </td>\n<td align=\"center\"> £2125 </td>\n</tr>\n\n</tbody></table>"
```

To get HTML of each row and put it in an array:

```
browser.table.trs.collect {|tr| tr.html}

=> ["<tr>\n<th> Address </th>\n<th> Council tax band </th>\n<th> Annual council tax </th>\n</tr>",
    "<tr>\n<td> 2, STONELEIGH AVENUE, COVENTRY, CV5 6BZ </td>\n<td align=\"center\"> F </td>\n<td align=\"center\"> £2125 </td>\n</tr>"]
```

To get text of each cell and put it in an array:

```
browser.table.trs.collect {|tr| [tr[0].text, tr[1].text, tr[2].text]}
=> [["Address", "Council tax band", "Annual council tax"],
    ["2, STONELEIGH AVENUE, COVENTRY, CV5 6BZ", "F", "£2125"]]
```

To write text of each cell to file:

```
content = b.table.trs.collect {|tr| [tr[0].text, tr[1].text, tr[2].text]}
File.open("table.txt", "w") {|file| file.puts content}
```

The file will look like this:

```
Address
Council tax band
Annual council tax
2, STONELEIGH AVENUE, COVENTRY, CV5 6BZ
F
£2125
```

Comment: This is definitely in-line with what I am looking for to get me started. I assume that if I wanted to save it as a .CSV file I would change ("table.txt", "w") to ("table.csv", "w").

Comment: After trying the above code I have encounted a small problem. I have stepped through and it works fine until I get to

'File.open("table.txt", "w") {|file| file.puts content}

Do I need to have required the Win32console? Do I need to have created the textfile and have it left open?

I am very new to this so please accept my apologies.

Comment: @user1077250: to create csv file you would also need to change the text being saved to file, just changing the file extension will not create properly formatted csv file

Comment: @user1077250: if you provide the error message you are getting when saving the file, I could tell more

Comment: @ Željko Filipin thanks for the advice. I have managed to write text to a file. Very pleased.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to approach this, if we know a bit more about what you are specifically trying to accomplish, then we can give you answers that are also a bit more specific instead of general.

You can use `.collect` as Zeljko has shown if you want to convert stuff to arrays.  If you just want to work with the data or iterate over the rows and cells in the table then `.each` or `.each_with_index` may be what you want.

I suspect you really want the text from the table, not the HTML.  So here's something to try (untested but it should work)

```
browser.table(:how => what).rows.each_with_index do |row, r|
  row.cells.each_with_index do |cell, c|
    puts "Row:#{r} Cell:#{c} text is: #{cell.text}"
  end
end
```

if `.rows` or `.cells` does not work (unknown method) in the above, try replacing with `.trs`
and `.tds` respectively (not all versions of watir have the friendly
aliases for those methods)

See if that spits out what you are interested in.   If so, you should be able to easily modify to write what you want to a file instead of putting it to the screen.

However if verification is your goal, then it might be easier to have the automation code look things up in the db and do the comparison for you.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative method. However I am little confused as to how I would write what I collected to a file. Would I  I am very new to watir so how would I use a similar method to what Zeljko suggested above?

Comment: @user1077250: I would suggest that you read about how Ruby works with files. Just google it. If you have a specific problem, ask.

Comment: Yes something similar..  the File IO is a part of basic Ruby stuff (not specific to Watir), and there are multiple ruby tutorials you can find that will cover how to work with files.  or I might recommend the excellent 'Everyday Scripting with Ruby' book by Brian Marick